# Java RegEx and linebreaks - bug or expected behavior?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to interpret a multiline string with RegEx and just found that matching will fail if the string contains newline characters. I'm NOT using using `MULTILINE` mode, because I'm not using anchors. According to API docs:

> In multiline mode the expressions ^
>   and $ match just after or just before,
>   respectively, a line terminator or the
>   end of the input sequence. By default
>   these expressions only match at the
>   beginning and the end of the entire
>   input sequence.

In short: it clearly says that this flag only changes how anchors work and says nothing like *"when your string contains a newline you should definitely use this"*.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*");

    Matcher m1 = p.matcher("Hello");
    System.out.println("m1: " + m1.matches());    // true

    Matcher m2 = p.matcher("Hello\r\n");
    System.out.println("m2: " + m2.matches());    // false
}
```

So is this really a bug, or I just missed some docs? Or JAVA uses a dialect of RegEx where my pattern fails? I'm using `jdk1.6.0_21`.

Comment: if you are using a standard Java API and it is not behaving as you expect, the thing you should be questioning is *your understanding* of the API ... rather than pursuing the theory that you've found a bug.

Comment: @Stephen I know, i know. But it never crossed my maind that `matches` matches against the whole string even when i don't use anchors. The JAVA API is the most consistent and well-planned thing I encountered this far in computing world, so I blindly believed that the method will work as I surmised.

Comment: If you think the Java API is “consistent and well-planned”, then you aren’t paying close enough attention. It very much is *not* such a thing!

Comment: @tchrist This topic would very well suit a chatroom, but I would not like to discuss it here, because it is a really wide and branching topic. (Some can even say subjective).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Pattern docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lt):

> The regular expression `.` matches any
>   character except a line terminator
>   unless the DOTALL flag is specified.

So you need to specify the `DOTALL` flag if you want `m2.matches()` to be true.

Comment: I have red that too, but note that the pattern is not `^.*$` or anything like that. I'm not using anchros, so `Hello` should be a match in the second case too.

Comment: `matches()` checks if the *entire* string matches the regular expression "`.*`". `.*` means "any character except a line break 0 or more times."  So it matches, `H`, matches `e` then `l` then `l` then `o`, then when it gets to the `\r` it does not match anymore and returns false.  Do you understand?  This code has to do with the behavior of the `.` character, not anchors.

Comment: So if you had the `DOTALL` flag enabled `m2` would match `Hello` and get to `\r\n`. The spec would now say "The regular expression `.` matches any character **including a line terminator**!" So `m2` would match `\r` and `\n` and return true.

Comment: @Philip Thnaks. I understand. Indeed I thought that `matches()` will be true if there is ANY match. If I want to match against the *wole* string I could add anchors to my pattern, so I find it a bit counter-intuitive, but I guess this is how it goes...

Comment: @vbence - the `find` method tells you if there is a partial match; i.e. the regex matches a substring.  The `matches` method tells you if there is a complete match; i.e. the regex matches the complete string.

Comment: @Philip Yep, but `find()` changes the state of the object too, not just an `isXxx` method.